# Apache forbidden access

Tags: apache

Here is a part of my httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory C:\wamp\www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And the error log says:

```
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/Bugzilla
```

I try to access:

```
localhost/bugzilla
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following:

```
<Directory "C:\wamp\www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: try putting 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: Do you have any.htaccess file in your bugzilla folder? Do you have C:/wamp/www/Bugzilla mentioned somewhere else in your apache config?

Comment: @rkosegi Yes I do have .htaccess file and I have: DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/" in the httpd.conf file

Comment: What is content of .htaccess? Maybe it overrides httpd.conf.Try to temporary remove it (or rename) to see if it has some effect on access.Also, did you restart your apache instance when making changes in httpd.conf?

Comment: @rkosegi I tried removing the file and now I am able to enter, but what is showing are files, and not web page.

Comment: @rkosegi I always restart the service.

Comment: @rkosegi ANd even in the folders I have .cgi files, they aren't shown in the browser

Comment: @Srcee so that's it. post content of htaccess file.

Comment: @rkosegi I changed the .htaccess file from 'deny' to 'allow', but now when I write the URL in the browser I get a list of the folders. Not a website.

Comment: Right question is what you expecting to view.I think this is related to "how to configure bugzilla" instead of "Apache forbidden access".Please check bugzilla documentation

Comment: @rkosegi Can you pls answer the question so that I can choose your answer as the best one?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to its config:

```
 Require all granted
```